# Fastest Count Vectorizer Implementation

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn, vectorization

I'm looking for an implementation of n-grams count vectorization that is more efficient than scikit-learn's `CountVectorizer`.  I've identified the `CountVectorizer.transform()` call as a huge bottleneck in a bit of software, and can dramatically increase model throughput if we're able to make this part of the pipeline more efficient.  Fit time is not important, we're only concerned with transform time.  The end output must be a `scipy.sparse` vector.  If anyone has any leads for potential alternatives it would be much appreciated.

Comment: What about a homebrewed implementation of counting over [mapreduce](https://github.com/michaelfairley/mincemeatpy)? You could convert to a sparse matrix afterwards.

Comment: We already have data parallelism (different processes deal with different chunks of data) so we likely won't see any increase in throughput from using mapreduce calls.  Thanks for the recommendation, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `HashingVectorizer`? It's slightly faster (up to 2X if I remember correctly). Next step is to profile the code, strip the features of `CountVectorizer` or `HashingVectorizer` that you don't use and rewrite the remaining part in optimized Cython code (after profiling again).

Vowpal Wabbit's bare-bone feature processing that uses the hashing trick by default might give you a hint of what is achievable.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Olivier.  I've seen marginal improvements with the HashingVectorizer (around 30% speedup).  We don't need to map back to the original vocabulary, so we will be using the HashingVectorizer moving forward.  I will also definitely try cythonization.  Profiling doesn't show any clear bottleneck in the `transform` call, so my guess is that cythonization is going to be the only real opportunity for speedup.

Comment: Also, we'll make sure to submit a PR if we do find any serious opportunity for increased efficiency without stripping functionality.

Comment: @MadisonMay so what's the end of the story, if it's not a secret? :)